Similar SVMs with only different misclassification weights!
I am working on understanding the relationship between the solutions of two related SVM optimization problems, defined as follows:

Problem 1:
\begin{equation}
   \min \frac{1}{2} \|w\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n  a_i \xi_i
   \quad 
   \mbox{subject to}:
   \quad 
   y_i (w^T x_i + b) \ge 1 - \xi_i, \quad \xi_i \geq 0.
   \end{equation}

Problem 2:
\begin{equation}
   \min \frac{1}{2} \|\bar{w}\|^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n \zeta_i a_i \bar{\xi}_i
   \quad \mbox{subject to:}
   \quad 
   y_i (\bar{w}^T x_i + \bar{b}) \ge 1 - \bar{\xi}_i, \quad \bar{\xi}_i \geq 0,
   \end{equation}


for where $\zeta\ge 0$ is given.
I hope that having the solution to the first problem will help us solve the second problem efficiently, but I have not been able to prove anything concrete yet. If one can characterize the solution of the second problem from the solution of the first problem and $\zeta_i$'s, that would be ideal but I do not think that can be done! However, I think the second problem does not need to be solved with all the sample points again; only some specific points should be considered. This condition should be probably based on how big the margin of $x_i$ is and $\zeta_i$!
KKT Conditions:
\begin{align*}
 & \quad y_i (\bar{w}^T x_i + \bar{b}) + \bar{\xi}_i \geq 1, \quad \bar{\xi}_i \geq 0. \\
& \quad \bar{w} = \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{\lambda}_i y_i x_i, \quad \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{\lambda}_i y_i = 0, \quad \bar \lambda_i+\bar \mu_i = C\zeta_ia_i \\
 & \quad \bar{\lambda}_i \left[ y_i (\bar{w}^T x_i + \bar{b}) - 1 + \bar{\xi}_i \right] = 0,\quad \bar{\mu}_i \bar{\xi}_i = 0. \\
& \quad \bar{\lambda}_i \geq 0, \quad \bar{\mu}_i \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Any help would be appreciated.

Since the first problem is a special case of the second, then the solution of the first is contained in the solution set of the second with respect to the weights. So there is no straightforward way to solve the second problem using a solution of the first in the general sense. However we may use the first solution as a starting point for the optimization algorithm of the second, in which case we may want an upper bound on the distance between the solutions.

I am not quite following because $\zeta$ is fixed and given. Unless $\zeta$ is a vector of ones, I do not think the solution to the first problem is inside the solution set of the second one. Btw, with respect to $w$, both problems have a unique solution.

@V.S.e.H. I think the $b$ part is unique for both problems as well.

Sorry for the confusion. I'm viewing the set of solutions to the second problem as parameterized by $\zeta$, i.e. $S = {x\in\mathbb{R}^p:x~\text{is a sol. of 2,} \zeta\in\mathbb{R}^n}$. The case $\zeta=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is the first problem as a special case of the second, therefore its solution is by definition in $S$.
